# traefik in a cascade with docker

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to run several totally independent services on the same computer.

Each should have its own subnet and needs a reverse proxy.

I would like to do the following setup:

```
traefik_main checks the domain (a.com or b.com) and routes the connection
to traefik_a or traefik_b

service1.a.com -> routed by traefik_a
service2.a.com -> routed by traefik_a
service1.b.com -> routed by traefik_b
service2.b.com -> routed by traefik_b
```

traefik_main, traefik_a and traefik_b would be in their own docker compose with their own services.

How can I get traefik_main to route connections to the other instances since they're on different subnets?